# does anybody know some free tool for monitoring synchronization between two MySQL databases for windows?

Tags: mysql, database

I have stetted up two databases which are synchronized with each other. But sometimes the sync process lags behind. I want to track this process and determine when the process is lagging?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to log into the database with a mysql client and run `show slave status\G` which will give you replication details including "seconds behind master".

For software options check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075433/mysql-monitor-replication

Answer (score 0):

Seconds_Behind_Master from SHOW SLAVE STATUS is considered an unreliable measure of Slave lag. [mk-heartbeat](http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-heartbeat.html) is often offered as a reliable alternative.